# Swift Symmetric Encryption with app passcode

Tags: ios, swift, encryption

I would be very helpful for some advice concerning data encryption with Swift CryptoKit.

## Aim

I want to AES encrypt some data, save it to the app bundle, and access it from the app once a user types a separate passcode. The passcode will be distributed separately and interact with a Symmetric Key somehow to decrypt the data. If the passcode is compromised, I can re-encrypt the data and update the app bundle with new encrypted data and distribute new passcode.

## Constraints

- The data must be included in the app bundle, no networking.
- TouchId is not available.
- If possible, I would like to avoid using the apple passcode system. Rather I want to ask for a passcode in the app itself, in order to use a custom passcode entry.

## What I have tried

I have made a symmetrical encryption command line program in Swift. This AES encrypts some local data, saves it and provides the key.

```
let keyForData = SymmetricKey(size: .bits256)
                
do {
// Get the documents
let fileURLs = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: inputDirURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
                    
for file in fileURLs {
   if (file.pathExtension == "json"){
       let fileName = String(file.path.split(separator: "/" ).last ?? "")
       consoleIO.writeMessage("Processing \(fileName)")
       let data = getData(file)
       // Encrytion
       let encryptedData = try! AES.GCM.seal(data, using: keyForData)
       let encryptedDataFileURL = outputDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName + ".enc")
       if let combinedData = encryptedData.combined {
           try combinedData.write(to: encryptedDataFileURL)
           consoleIO.writeMessage("File saved to \(encryptedDataFileURL.path.split(separator: "/" ).last ?? "")")
       } else {
           consoleIO.writeMessage("Problem daving encrypted file")
       }
   }
}
let keyString = keyForData.serialize()
let fileName = ".KEY_DO_NOT_COMMIT"
let encryptedKeyURL = outputDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
try keyString.write(to: encryptedKeyURL, atomically: false, encoding: .utf8)
consoleIO.writeMessage("Key saved to \(fileName)")
```

Now in the device bundle I have the encrypted data and the key.

Apple advises storing the key in the Keychain. Or storing it in the Secure Enclave.

This is where I get stuck on best practice.

## Ideas for implementation

1. Save key in Keychain on first load, then delete key. (This seems insecure and does not combine the Symmetric Key with the device Passcode.)
2. Pass a passcode to the command line app, use that to "scramble" the Symmetric Key, then save the symmetric key to the keychain and "de-scramble" when user enters passcode for app. (This seems to make sense but I am not sure how to "scramble" a Symmetric Key using a string in Swift.)
3. On first load, use passcode and Symmetric Key to somehow create key pair in Secure Enclave. On future opening of app, passcode provides Symmetric Key. The issue with this seems to be that the Secure Enclave never asks for a part of the key to store, it just provides a key pair to use, but in my case one half of the key pair already exists.

I understand if your answer is "Just go and learn crypto operations". To be honest I have read several articles: [Generating New Cryptographic Keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/generating_new_cryptographic_keys#2863927), [CryptoKit and Secure Enclave](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/cryptokit-secure-enclave/), [Common CryptoKit operation](https://www.andyibanez.com/posts/common-cryptographic-operations-with-cryptokit/), and I am not able to see a use case where a passcode is involved. I would be very grateful for a point on the right direction.

The key here is that I want the passcode I select at encryption time to some how interact with the encryption key. And if that encyption key can be stored in Secure Enclave that would be the icing on the cake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**THIS IS NOT TESTED AND I CANNOT BE SURE IS BEST PRACTICE.**

My solution is to use a Key Derivation Function (KDF) [more info](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40757/key-derivation-functions-kdf-what-are-main-purposes-how-can-they-be-used). From my learning this takes two inputs the passcode and a salt, and produces a key. The passcode I can then keep secret and the salt can accompany the data. One important aspect it seems is to have different salts for each item of data.

This code example helped me understand:

https://gist.github.com/hfossli/7165dc023a10046e2322b0ce74c596f8

Specifically:

```
let password = "foo"
let salt = randomSalt()

let key = try createKey(password: password.data(using: .utf8)!, salt: salt)


func randomSalt() -> Data {
    return randomData(length: 8)
}

func createKey(password: Data, salt: Data) throws -> Data {
    let length = kCCKeySizeAES256
    var status = Int32(0)
    var derivedBytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: length)
    password.withUnsafeBytes { (passwordBytes: UnsafePointer<Int8>!) in
        salt.withUnsafeBytes { (saltBytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>!) in
            status = CCKeyDerivationPBKDF(CCPBKDFAlgorithm(kCCPBKDF2),                  // algorithm
                                          passwordBytes,                                // password
                                          password.count,                               // passwordLen
                                          saltBytes,                                    // salt
                                          salt.count,                                   // saltLen
                                          CCPseudoRandomAlgorithm(kCCPRFHmacAlgSHA1),   // prf
                                          10000,                                        // rounds
                                          &derivedBytes,                                // derivedKey
                                          length)                                       // derivedKeyLen
        }
    }
    guard status == 0 else {
        throw Error.keyGeneration(status: Int(status))
    }
    return Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(derivedBytes), count: length)
}
```

You then have the key to use in the symetric encryption. And you can derive it from the passcode and salt in the app.

This was probably more of a question for crypto.stackexchange.com but I have tried to answer it with some pointes in the right direction.

THIS IS NOT TESTED AND I CANT BE SURE IS BEST PRACTICE.